# Is there a more formal word/phrase for "as well as"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

As the heading says: is there a more formal word or phrase for "as well as"? I can think of two expressions with this exact meaning – "as well as" and "along with" – but I have a feeling that neither is used in formal writing – or am I wrong about this?

Example (X stands for the word/phrase I'm looking for):

> All proposals, X any support documents, should be submitted to the committee no later than June 1.

Thank you!

Comment: More formal word? All proposals (along) with any support documents etc.

Comment: in addition to,

Comment: @Lambie so you'd say *along with* is fine in formal writing? That's great! Thanks!

Comment: @FredoonFarokh Uh... I can't believe I didn't think of that myself... Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Any of the following would work here:

All proposals, **with** any support documents, should be submitted to the committee no later than June 1.

All proposals, **including** any support documents, should be submitted to the committee no later than June 1.

All proposals **and supporting documents** should be submitted to the committee no later than June 1.